# Make uploaded video on youtube publicly

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii

I m using Yii framework and I want to upload video directly to you tube from my website. For that,i have used
 http://yii.hugphp.com/wiki/375/youtube-api-v2-0-browser-based-uploading/
Using this i am able to upload the video but it is giving the private access to uploaded video.I am able to play the uploaded video but anyone else can not view that video.

How can i make the video available publicly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you followed the file names in the tutorial, remove `$video->setVideoPrivate();` in video.php